# Output of a shell script to chef recipe vaiable-backticks not wokring

Tags: ruby, shell, chef-infra

Hi I am trying to get a output of a shell script to set to the variable inside a chef recipe but i couldnt see that variable is not set properly; i have tried it in three ways:

1.) set it directly as below:

```
password = "`/home/#{OWNER}/fox/get_secretsmanager_pwd.sh '#{KEYSTORE_NAME}' 'password'`"
```

2.) Tried the below:

```
ruby_block 'Get ' do
  block do
    node.set['test']['password'] = "`/home/#{OWNER}/fox/get_secret_pwd.sh '#{KEYSTORE_NAME}' 'password' `"
    Chef::Log.info("password: #{node['test']['password']}")
  end
  action :run
end
```

3.)Tried it in the below way as well:

```
ruby_block 'Get ' do
  block do
    Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)
    command = "`/home/#{OWNER}/fox/get_secrets_pwd.sh '#{KEYSTORE_NAME}' 'password' `"
    command_out = shell_out(command)
    node.set['test']['password'] = command_out.stdout
    Chef::Log.info("password2: #{node['test']['password']}")
  end
  action :run
end
```

This script (/home/#{OWNER}/fox/get_secrets_pwd.sh '#{KEYSTORE_NAME}' 'password' ) will return a text from DB.

Comment: You’re quoting the backticks, so they aren’t calling a command.

Comment: Your foodcritic rules are telling you not to use `node.set` because that persists on the node where `node.default` and `node.override` do not.  You should never use 'node.set' (and that API has been removed in Chef 13+).  Also since chef nodes can read other nodes node data, the password values that you are writing to the node are effectively published to your entire organization and any compromised server in it.  You should use either a plain ruby variable, or should use `node.run_state['test']['password']` instead to keep that value local to the node and not publish it.

Answer (score 3):

### Don't Quote Your Backticks

This is caused by a subtle syntax issue that won't raise an error. You're assigning a fixed string to your node attribute, not the output of your command, because you're quoting the backticks!

There may be other problems with your code, but if you change:

> ```
> node.set['test']['password'] = "`/home/#{OWNER}/fox/get_secret_pwd.sh '#{KEYSTORE_NAME}' 'password' `"
> ```

to:

```
node.set['test']['password'] =
  `/home/#{OWNER}/fox/get_secret_pwd.sh '#{KEYSTORE_NAME}' 'password')`
```

then it should correctly assign the output of your command to the node attribute.

Comment: thanks jacob. after removing the backticks in shellout it worked.There are foodcritic rule set in our organisation which stop to use to directly use it like node.set['test']['password'] =
  `/home/#{OWNER}/fox/get_secret_pwd.sh '#{KEYSTORE_NAME}' 'password')`

Comment: I am getting the below error while applying the recipe:
  Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
  ----------------------------------
  Property storepass must be one of: String!  You passed nil.

since i have set the password using the above logic and pass it to another ruby block code. During compilation its failing since its checking during intialisation, Could you please let me know how we can solve this issue?